# Error while executing Selenium script in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, selenium

I am getting the below error for the below script. I have all the jar files added to the library.

```
============================================================
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type
    FirefoxDriver cannot be resolved to a type

    at webdriver/Demo.Sample.main(Sample.java:11)
=============================================================
```

```java
package Demo;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("hello");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Anita Tiwari, it seems like, you haven't added web driver libraries to your project. Try to download and add web driver jar files as per your requirement and try again.

Comment: hi @Ali CSE, I have added JAVA version 3.141.59 under Selenium Client & WebDriver Language Bindings from site https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/      and then added the jar files to project libs.

Comment: How are you running your code? Are you using any IDE? This is a compilation error and your program is not able to detect/import `WebDriver` and `FirefoxDriver`... How are you adding jars? Can you share the build path snapshot?

Comment: I am running the code using Eclipse IDE - Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
Build id: 20181214-0600

Comment: here is the screenshot of build path][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlMWo.png

Comment: I have added an answer, try to follow it. Download `selenium-server-standalone`, `geckodriver` compatible with your `firefox` browser version. Remove other jars which you have added previously to your build path and import only `selenium-server-standalone` jar now. Provide your system executable binary path of `geckodriver` in `System.setProperty()` then rest will work fine... Let me know if you are facing any issues again, thank you...

Comment: Thanks Ali. I was able to fix the jar file issue after downloading file selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar file. I did download the gecko driver and set the path , Firefox browser is opening but google is not opening. I am getting below error https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6fEa.png.I did try with different Firefox versions but keep getting error.

Comment: I have few more questions since I am beginner level to learn Selenium. The latest selenium version is 3.141.59 then why we need to use selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar to make firefox code work? 2.53.1 jar should also work for Chrome browser? Also, do you recommend to use specific Eclipse IDE for Selenium as there are different packages https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Comment: You can use any Eclipse package of your choice and you can use latest selenium version also but the thing is in the latest selenium version, `selenium server` is not there and your browser should be up to date. I think the reason for your error is, your version of selenium is not compatible with your firefox version so try to download and import latest version of selenium and try again...

Comment: Thanks Ali. I was able to open both FF and Chrome browser successfully with latest version of selenium with Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.

Comment: That's good news...! Congratulations and Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, you have imported the wrong jar files. Download the `selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar` file from https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.53/ and import it into an eclipse and remove other jar files.

Since you are trying to automate Firefox using Selenium WebDriver, you need to download Firefox executable binary file as well. Based on your browser version, you can get `gecko` driver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/

And add the below line in your code before the driver initialization and provide absolute path of Firefox executable binary file with name and extention :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", "pathToGeckoBinaryExecutable");
```

Below is your modified code :

```
package Demo;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", "pathToGeckoBinaryExecutable\\geckodriver.exe"); // Provide your system path to the gecko driver with name and extension here
        System.out.println("hello");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

I hope it helps...